# Search.asp file won't function

Tags: asp-classic

When I click on the search link to search archived files on my internal server, the screen displays the search.asp file's code, instead of functioning as it should. How can I update the asp file to direct to my new server?

Comment: You need to configure IIS to execute ASP files.

Answer (score 0):

More recent versions of IIS do not execute Classic ASP out-of-the-box. You will need to enable ASP processing yourself. The particulars depend a little on which version of IIS you are running.

For example, according to [IIS.net](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis) you would need to go to the Server Manager, and check the box next to "ASP" under "Application Development".

Comment: I think it's just a revision I need to make to the search.asp file. IIS should already be configured. We just moved from numerical URL to internal server (file:///M etc.) URL. So it's just needs to be redirected. But I don't see how to do it in the .asp file.